# Проблема с позиционированием элементов в IB

Tags: objective-c

Приветствую. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли отступы между парой смежных компонентов сделать плавающими и равными друг другу (компоненты имеют фиксированную ширину)?

В общем, надо, чтобы:
1) вертикальные отступы между парой смежных компонентов (включая navigationBar и toolBar) были равными (независимо от ориентации и разновидности уст-ва)
2) topBar и bottomBar привязаны к верхней и, соответственно, к нижней границам view
2) высота элементов со 2-го по 4-й одинакова и ограничена (h1 <= h <= h2)
3) высота 1-го равна высоте последнего и также масштабируется в ограниченных рамках (по высоте)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дополните пожалуйста вопрос кодом.

Comment: Так проблема с расположением в Interface Builder.

Comment: Нарисуйте хоть схематически что Вы имеете в виду. Из того что представил по описанию можно, но может не то представил.

Comment: Сделано! Уже каких вариантов только не перепробовал... к сожалению, всё безуспешно. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для разных ориентаций выбираете необходимую constraint, нажимаете на плюсик возле constant и добавляете:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем задаете нужный размер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я правильно понял мысль, то можете глянуть [результат на GitHub](https://github.com/VAndrJ/TestElementsSizesForSO)

1. Отступы между элементами одинаковы
2. Первый и последний элементы одинаковы по высоте и имеют высоту в % от высоты экрана.
3. 2-4 равны между собой и меньше 1.

Скрины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. А не подскажете, можно ли каким-то образом в зависимости от ориентации устройства регулировать величину отступа между компонентами?

Comment: @Герман обновил ответ.

Comment: XCode 4.6 похоже, что не поддерживает применение связей к объектам в различных ориентациях. Неужели придётся под разные ориентации отдельно каждый xib делать?